# wordpress switching between old and new theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I have just finished a custom theme and activated it.. But - it keeps switching back and forth between the old theme and my new one - seemingly at random. I used **theme test drive** when i was developing the new theme - could this have any effect?

When i do get the new theme to show up i can navigate around the site - but when i go for the "home" link i always get the old theme showing again on the index page.

Any idea as to what could be causing the problem?? I have emptied all caches several times but with no succes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using total cache plugin and disabling everything related to caches.. a bit rough but it did the trick!